# Angular 9 : re-render ngFor when object property is updated

Tags: angular

I have an array of Objects, which I called Guests :

```
[
   {id: 1, first_name: "Tom", last_name: "", logo: 2},
   {id: 2, first_name: "John", last_name: "", logo: 3},
   {id: 3, first_name: "Jim", last_name: "", logo: 4}
]
```

And I display those objects in a `ngFor`, which works perfectly:

```
<app-guest-item *ngFor="let guest of guests;"
                [guest]="guest"
></app-guest-item>
```

My `app-guest-item` only displays the data like so:

```
<p>{{guest.name}}</p>
<img src="assets/logo/{{guest.logo}.png" alt={{guest.name}}/>
<p>Status: {{guest.online}}</p>
```

But whenever my array changes, like so:

```
[
   {id: 1, first_name: "Tom", last_name: "", logo: 2, online: true},
   {id: 2, first_name: "John", last_name: "", logo: 3},
   {id: 3, first_name: "Jim", last_name: "", logo: 4}
]
```

The ngFor does not re-render.

**Note that the array is updated with an *EventSource* like so:**

```
this.updateGuests = new EventSource('http://localhost:3000/.well-known/mercure?topic=table-1');
this.updateGuests.onmessage = event => {
    this.guests = JSON.parse(event.data).onlineGuests;
}
```

### What I tried

#### Adding a `trackBy`

```
<app-guest-item *ngFor="let guest of guests; trackBy: trackGuest"
                [guest]="guest"
></app-guest-item>
```

with the following method. By the way, I am sure my Guests have all a unique `id`:

```
public trackGuest(index: number, item: GuestModel) {
    return item.id;
  }
```

#### Change my list reference

When my guest list is updated, I tried to change its reference by doing so:

```
this.guests = [...this.guests];
```

It did not work... So far I am lost.

Comment: What is happening in the app-guest-item component? Does it detect changes to the input?

Comment: No, it only displays the information of the guest. I will add this in the post

Comment: `this.guests = [...this.guests];` and removing `*trackBy` should do the trick for you (it will re-render the guest components from scratch). a better performance-wise solution seems to require something like `this.guest[index] = {...this.guests[index], online: isOnline}` to change the object reference

Comment: Just tried your method, but it did not work. Why should I remove the trackBy AND change the list reference ?

Comment: Are you using onPush change detection strategy?

Comment: Could you please reproduce the issue on stackblitz and so share it? it would really be helpful :)

Comment: you have this.Guests in the javascript instead of this.guests.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed this (it was a typo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, the issue was pretty simple:

The array is updated in an **EventSource**, and EventSource events are out of scope from the Angular change detection mechanism.

To make this change detectable by the Angular detection mechanism, you just have to say explicitly that this change should be monitored by Angular with an [ngZone](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone).

To do so, simply add the `ngZone` as a parameter in your constructor:

```
constructor(private zone: NgZone) {}
```

And then update the portion of your code when you update your guest list with:

```
this.updateGuests.onmessage = event => {
  this.zone.run(() => {
    this.guests = JSON.parse(event.data).onlineGuests;
  });
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the only change needed was changing this.Guests to this.guests.

Comment: This was a typo. It was this.guests (and not this.Guests)